# Menu button disappears when action bar is hidden in Kitkat

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

I'm developing an android app which doesn't have an action bar. I have the sign out and sync options as menu items. When I tried this in my Nexus 5, the menu button is nowhere to be found. It usually appears in the action bar. Is there a way to keep the menu button and hide the action bar at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to keep the menu button and hide the action bar at the same time?

No. If you are not going to use the action bar, you cannot reliably use `<menu>` resources. Please put "sign out and sync options" in your own GUI, such as via buttons.

Note that [the MENU key is itself deprecated now](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/12/09/menu-key-dead-again.html); few devices going forward will have one.